# How can non-existence be caused?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

If something didn't exist and came to exist at some point; it will cease to exist at some point. Things come from non-existence and return to the non-existence they came from so how can "non-existence" be caused? I fail to see how what they originally came from (non-existence) is "caused" at any point of existence?

Comment: Is this question asking about (1) the event of coming into existence, (2) the event of going out of existence, (3) the thing which comes and goes, (4) the *label* "non-existence", and or (5) the *thing* "non-existence"?

Comment: As soon as you, _subject_, address "non-existence", such _object_ comes into existence, and it is you that have created it (by means of the abstract interaction object - subject). Whatever its meaning.

Comment: As @Michael comments it is not clear what you are asking. Could you please illustrate your question by a simple example, with simple words. Avoiding heavy terminology as "non-existence being caused". Then one can better see which philosophical terms could help to iluminate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is my interpretation of your question; if it doesn't really fit, oh well, but maybe I'll still say something relevant in the follow-up:

> If something has a cause, it is an effect. If something is an effect, it is something, i.e. it exists. Causing nonexistence would be causing a nonexistent effect, i.e. not causing something. Ergo, how is it possible for things to cease to exist? And if something doesn't exist, then it doesn't cause anything, and nothing can be an effect on it; ergo, it is not possible to have an effect on a nonexistent thing, to the effect that it then exists.

This actually looks like a really good argument, to me. I'm not sure I disagree with it directly; although I countenance the meaningfulness of "doesn't exist," I do so in the context of the impredicative syntax of quantifiers in standard contemporary logic. "At worst," the assertion *that X does not exist* can be repurposed as *there are zero concrete objects satisfying the abstract X-description*, or something along that line, then. We're still committed to the existence of zero, to be sure, but this is not quite the same at all as being committed to the existence of a self-participating Form of Nonexistence, say.

Anyway, there are different ways to approach, and cash out, the above problem. Let's say causality is a propositional relation: facts [Quinewise equivalent to "proposition-like slices of physical reality"] are the causes and effects. If *X* doesn't exist, it's a fact that *X* doesn't exist; but also the proposition, "*X* exists," itself exists, despite being false. A cause of *X* coming to exist would be causing the fact that *X* exists, and would act on the proposition, "*X* exists," or, "There is at least one *X*," so it would be acting on something that does exist. Then the existence of *X* proper would effectively be distilled out of a sort of logical ether; but I expect this sense of things was where Frege was going already with his talk of truth values.

Or maybe we're dealing with obtaining vs. unobtaining states of affairs. These are quasi-sentential reality-slices: *X's existing*, *X's coming into existence,* *X's not existing,* etc. So we attach the causal relation to states of affairs, and say something like, "The obtaining of state-of-affairs *A* causes the obtaining of *B*," and if these states of affairs are paraeternal abstractions like propositions might be, then we still have an action of an existent on another existent. [Consider: *X's not existing* is different from *Y's not existing*, even if neither *X* nor *Y* actually exist.]

OTOH, vs. the above, it is also usually said that abstract objects are causally inert (this was far from Plato's assessment of the situation, for whom the Form of the Good was hardly acausal, even with respect to the other Forms). So it might be hard to think of physical causes and effects somehow precipitating into being out of the abstract realm.

Answer (score -1):

A non-existence claim about something can be asserted on the basis that for example some other attribute of the physical universe which is known to exist mathematically rules out that particular thing.

We consider for example Noether's Theorem which states that for any *mathematical continuous symmetry* exhibited by a mathematical representation of a dynamical physical system, there then exists another mathematical object called a *conserved quantity*.

If the system dynamics are symmetric with respect to position in 3-dimensional space, then there exists a conserved quantity which we have named *linear momentum*.

If the system dynamics are symmetric with respect to direction in 3-dimensional space, then there exists a conserved quantity which we have named *angular momentum*.

If the system dynamics are symmetric with respect to time in 3-dimensional space, then there exists a conserved quantity which we have named *energy*.

The conservation of linear momentum then establishes the nonexistence of a privileged location in the universe. The conservation of angular momentum then establishes the nonexistence of a privileged direction in the universe. The conservation of energy then establishes the nonexistence of a privileged time in the universe.